# Assume G is a group, x,y is in G; x and y are not identity, but $x^3=1$ and $y^2=1$ and $(xy)^2=1$. Find the order of G and the group table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

So I am stuck with this problem and I can't seem to find the relationship with the x, y and identity in dealing with size of group and how they connect with $(xy)^2=1$.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What strange wording, all groups are closed, so I wonder what the $xy\in G$ means.

Comment: There's probably a missing comma. It should be $x,y \in G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, now I feel like a complete idiot...

Comment: Note that $(xy)^2=1$ is equivalent to $yxy=x^{-1}$ and, since $y^2=1$, this is the same as $y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}$. So $\langle x \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of order $3$, with quotient group of order $2$.

Comment: Something something, $S_3$

Comment: Unless $x$ and $y$ generate the group this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(xy)^2=1$, which means $xy=(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx^2$. Thus, every element of $G$ can be reduced to a form $y^ix^j$, where $i=0,1$ and $j=0,1,2$ (since $y^2=1=x^3$). Thus there are *at most* six elements in $G$. You can check in fact it is *equal* to $6$.